# Calling Python script from C++ for constantly streaming data

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning

I'm working with testing a neural network model on hardware and have the model code in Python and hardware code in C++.

From the C++ code, I'm calling

```
system("python file.py")
```

to run my Python script containing the model, along with the pre-processing and post-processing steps.
There's a lot of sequential data I want the model to be able to process, but I want it to be real-time (so as fast as possible). As a result, I'd like to split up my python file into 2 pieces - one with the pre-processing steps (such as loading the model/files) and the other with the actual inference step (which will be run for each piece of data for each second).

But, how do I do that in my C++ code?

If I call:

```
system("python preprocessing.py")
```

and then

```
system("python inference.py")
```

they won't be connected right? Inference.py will have no clue what happened in the preprocessing step.
Basically, my question is - how can I maintain state between the 2 python script calls that I'm making from C++?

Is it possible that I call the preprocessing step and then somehow "wait" for further input and then perform inference on each sequential input?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to have a single python script and have different functions within the script, say `preprocess` and `infer`. Then use the embed script approach to call the functions within the script. Unless you have to pass a lot of variables to the python functions it is pretty straight forward.

The example program from the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/embedding.html) works without much modification. Look at section 1.3

Basically you need to call the `Py_Initialize`function then load the module, get the function pointer corresponding to the functions in the script and then call them.

Hope that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a python expert, but I would approach this problem differently - I would keep the python script as 1 file and use Interprocess communication between the C++ and Python programs to transfer signals (i.e. - new data is available).

Essentially, the python script will do the initial setup/preprocessing and then wait for a signal from the C++ app that the data is ready for processing (i.e. busy wait or sleep on an event).

The simplest way to do it is to leave a message in a common file, but I am sure there are several other methods that windows provides (such as interprocess mutexs or message queues).

Hope this gives you a plan...

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a very interesting idea that could work. Would you happen to know of any mini examples I can refer to?

Comment: Sorry, but no.
If you dont want to get into a fuss - A file can easily be a solution (although an ugly one) - Create a file when you have new data, delete if when your done....
Sockets are also an option (use 127.0.0.1 as IP address), or search for windows interprocess mutex/queues in google.